# Efficently create a new df column based on another row for very large df

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a three-columns numerical dataframe, and I'm trying to add a 4th column which is basically the previous week stock for the sku item. Let's take an easy example:

Input:

```
   sku_id  week  stock
0       1    10    100
1       2     1     50
2       2     3     10
3       2     2     30
4       1    11     50
```

Desired output:

```
   sku_id  week  stock  stock_week_minus_one
0       1    10    100                   NaN
1       2     1     50                   NaN
2       2     3     10                  30.0
3       2     2     30                  50.0
4       1    11     50                 100.0
```

NB: as you can see, rows are not sorted by sku_id, neither by week number.

I wrote a few lines of code to do this:

```
new_col = []
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    previous_res_list=df.loc[(df.week==(row.week-1))& (df.sku_id==(row.sku_id))].stock.values
    if len(previous_res_list)==0:
        new_col.append(None)
        continue
    new_col.append(previous_res_list[0])
df[f"stock_week_minus_one"]=new_col
```

Unfortunately this takes forever to run as my dataframe contains 1.8M rows.
Do you know any faster and more efficient way to do this? Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use itertuples, might be a little faster. Try something like this:

```
import pandas as pd

sku_id = (1, 2, 2, 2, 1)
week = (4, 1, 3, 2, 5)
stock = (100, 50, 0, 30, 50)
df = pd.DataFrame(data={"sku_id": sku_id, "week": week, "stock": stock})

previous_week_stock = []

for row in df.itertuples():
    stock = df.loc[(df.week == row.week -1) & (df.sku_id == row.sku_id)].stock.values
    if stock.size:
        stock = stock[0]
    else:
        stock = None
    previous_week_stock.append(stock)

df["previous_week_stock"] = previous_week_stock
```

To test whether it is faster you could use time:

```
import time

start_time = time.time()

# All the code

print(f"Code executed in {time.time() - start_time)/60}")
```

With such little df like the one I have I cannot really test speed. Hope it helps!